# Easiest way of displaying certain fields and submit buttons on a sidebar (a la WordPress)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So, I want to archive something like this:

[image]

I want to have tag, image fields, submit, and save as draft submit buttons in a sidebar.

Right now, the structure is like this:

[image]

**new.html.erb:**

```
<% provide(:title, 'Create post') %>

<h1 class="navless-title">Create post</h1>

<%= form_for(@post, remote: true, :html => { :multipart => true }) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'fields', f: f %>
  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.submit "Publish", class: "publish btn btn-primary pull-left" %>
    <%= f.submit "Save Draft", class: "save-draft btn btn-default pull-left" %>
    <div class="busy pull-left"></div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**fields.html.erb:**

```
<%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

<%= f.label :title %>
<%= f.text_field :title %>

<%= f.label :content %>
<%= f.text_area :content, id: "wysihtml5-textarea" %>

<%= f.label :tag_list, "Tags" %>
<%= f.text_field :tag_list, "data-pre" => @post.tags.map(&:attributes).to_json %>

<%= f.label :image %>
<%= f.file_field :image %>

<p class="status">
  <% if @post.id? && @post.status == "Draft" %>
    Status: <span class="label"><%= @post.status %></span>
  <% elsif @post.id? && @post.status == "Published" %>
    Status: <span class="label label-primary"><%= @post.status %></span>
  <% end %>
</p>

<%= render 'shared/editor_toolbar' %>
```

So, I'm not sure what to do; either using absolute positioning, jQuery, or cutting the form into half (not sure if this is possible).

What's the easiest way of doing this?